# Alternative To Greenshot for Linux( With Exporting Screenshots to a file .Eg Word or docx file

Tags: linux, screenshot, arch-linux

I want to take screenshots of window and want to save it in a doc file(or any format in which I can also write few lines later eg Docx) then again when I take a screenshot the second screenshot should be saved on the same file and so on for rest of screen-shots.
Recently I have shifted to Manjaro (arch) Linux earlier I achieved this by using greenshot on Windows).